# formatter plot point dont work

Tags: ajax, plot, highcharts, scatter

I am new in [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/) users and I want to get [scatter plot](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter) graph but with some conditions. I have this data that I get by JSON from a PHP function like that:

```
jsonObjOrd (by json)=== > [[26.4,77.5,"US009"],[8.3,6.6,"US013"],[5.8,6.1,"US015"],[4.1,5.1,"US020"],[19,20.6,"US021"],[14.4,26.5,"US022"]]
```

and I wrote this code :

```
<div id="containerShow" style="height: 400px; width: 900px"></div>
```

until now it is good but I would like to see this in the little box when I hover a plot/point:

```
Site: US015
X: 5.8
Y: 6.1

Site: US016
X: 7.8
Y: 5.1
```

Does anyone of you know how to display this data in the little box?

Comment: $.getJSON('/test/scatter/', function(json){


            console.log(json['arrayJson']);
            var fileName   = JSON.parse(json['fileName']);
            var jsonObjOrd = JSON.parse(json['arrayJson']);
            var siteName = JSON.parse(json['site']);

            var tabSite = [];
            //var i = 0;
            $.each(siteName, function(key, res){
                var site = res['siteName'];
                tabSite.push(site);

            });

Comment: you can see my code here
http://jsfiddle.net/5f3f4nfe/

Comment: Use `pointFormat` and `headerFormat` options? You have them already in the code.